# Height of the tree : $T(n) = 4T(n/4)+2T(5n/8)+T(n/8)+\theta(1)$

Tags: algorithms, trees

Let the tree described by $T(n) = 4T(n/4)+2T(5n/8)+T(n/8)+\theta(1)$

Can someone explains why the height is $\log_{8/5}{n}$ I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the tree is determined by the slowest process, $T(n/b)$. The last leaf on the tree has $T(n/b^{\text{height}})=O(1)$, and therefore the height of the tree is: $$\text{height}=\log_b n = \log_{8/5}n$$